# how to parse this JSON data {"A":"[[a,b],[c,d]]"}

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse this format of data by JSON --- `{"A":"[[a,b],[c,d]]"}` . I want to retrieve values a,b,c,d separately.
IF I DO `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` This shows me proper response. 
I Tried following things to parse but didnt work.

1. `alert(data.A[0]);`
2. `alert(data.[0]);`
3. `alert(data.A);`

data is JSONOBJECT HERE.

1 and 2 does not work at all.

3 at least show me undefined. Please someone tell me how i can retrieve this format.

Comment: So you don't have JSON, you have an object, otherwise you wouldn't be able to do JSON.stringify on the ***plain javascript object*** ?

Comment: And `data.A` is a string ?

Comment: you mean data is not JSONobject here ?

Comment: data.A print "undefined" in alert

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gUpSJ/

Comment: you have JSON, inside of your JSON. that suggests that your JSON generation script isn't written properly.

Comment: @gSingh: There's no such thing as a "JSONobject" in JavaScript.

Comment: @KevinB  i am printing the response in java like this out.print(jsonMap.toString());

Comment: @RocketHazmat  okay that is java script object than ....can u tell me how i can access the values ....i am sending this response from my java code out.print(jsonMap.toString());

Comment: also if i alert(data) than i got [object,object]

Comment: @gSingh: Don't use `alert()`.  Try `console.dir(data)`.  That should help you see what it *really* is and how to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check console

```
data = {"A":"[[a,b],[c,d]]"} ;
console.log(data.A);
```

> "[[a,b],[c,d]]"
> This is not javascript object . Its a string

If you want to use it as a javascript collection

Use as follows

> data = {"A":[["a","b"],["c","d"]]} ;
>
> console.log(data.A[0]); //=>["a", "b"]
>
> console.log(data.A[0]); //=>["c","d"]

Comment: even if i convert this to json object like this it dint work for me var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: You dont need to parse json . You just need to make the javascript collection proper

Comment: if you see my first option that is same as what you send but that didnt work ..i already tried alert(data.A[0])... is i am not understanding you properly ?

Comment: oh sorry thanks, can you also tell me how can i convert {"A":"[[a,b],[c,d]]"} ;    into this {"A":[["a","b"],["c","d"]]} ;     is there any command of JSON for that ?

Answer (score 0):

change your json object by data={A:[['a','b'],['c','d']]} . you can now access data.A[0][0], data.A[0][1]...